# How to append from a dataframe to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe called pop_emoj that has two columns (one for the emoji, and one for the emoji count) as seen below.

```
☕    585
    193
    186
     85
     53
    124
    138
     46
    170
    506
```

I have sorted the df based on the counts in descending order as seen below.

```
emoji_updated = pop_emoj.head(105).sort_values(ascending=False)
    1809
    1481
    1382
    1078
    1028
```

And I'm trying to use the top *n* emojis to append to a new list called top_list, but I am getting stuck. Here is my code so far.

```
def top_number_of_emojis(n):
    
    top_list = []
    top_list = emoji_updated[0].tolist()
    
    return top_list
```

I'm wanting to take all of column 1 (the emojis) and append them to my list (top_number_of_emojis). The output should look like this:

```
top_number_of_emojis(1) == ['']
top_number_of_emojis(2) == ['', '']
top_number_of_emojis(3) == ['', '', '']
```

Comment: What is column name for your emojis?

Comment: Do you simply want the nth emoji, or do you want the top n emojis?

Answer (score 0):

if you already got the top 5 emojis, you just need to save them to a list.
An option for that is iterrows.

```
top_list = []

for id, emoji in emoji_updated.iterrows():
    top_list.append(emoji)
```